# Type Mismatch when using Evaluate function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code to evaluate the difference between string and string without the letter "B" (the number of B is a min of 1 and max of 3). This code only needs to run when the target cell contains "CS55" and "B". When I test run this code, error message "Type mismatch always pops up.

these strings are always in this format: Paint,CS55,B/G, Paint,CS55,B/R/B, Paint,CS55,R/B, Paint,CS55,B/W

below is the part of the code that does the evaluate

```
If Cells(lrNew, "K").Value Like "*CS55*" Then                                                                    
     n = ws1.Evaluate("LEN)(" & Cells(lrNew, 11).Address & "-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" & Cells(lrNew, 11).Address & ",""B"","""")")
    End If`

full code:

    `Sub PaintCS55()
    Dim lrNew As Long, n1 As Long, n2 As Long, adr As String, n As Long

    lrNew = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    sr = 2

    If Cells(lrNew, "K").Value Like "*CS55*" Then
     n = ws1.Evaluate("LEN)(" & Cells(lrNew, 11).Address & "-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" & Cells(lrNew, 11).Address & ",""B"","""")")
    End If

    If Cells(lrNew, "K").Value Like "*CS55**B*" And _
       n = 1 Then
         n1 = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("C" & sr & ":C" & lr), Range("K" & sr & ":K" & lr), "*CS55**B*")
         n2 = n1 * 0.000666 * 7.48
    End If

    If Cells(lrNew, "K").Value Like "*CS55**B*" And _
       n = 2 Then
         n1 = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("C" & sr & ":C" & lr), Range("K" & sr & ":K" & lr), "*CS55**B*")
         n2 = n1 * 0.000666 * 7.48 * 2
    End If

    lrNew = lrNew + 1
    Cells(lrNew, "A") = Cells(lr, "A")
    Cells(lrNew, "B") = "."
    Cells(lrNew, "C") = n2
    Cells(lrNew, "D") = "F62655"
    Cells(lrNew, "I") = "Purchased"
    Cells(lrNew, "K") = "CS55 Black"
    If Cells(lrNew, "C").Value Like "*0*" Then
        Rows(lrNew).Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

link to a test file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2yk9zsqpeov9yxh/2022100191%20PAINT%201.csv?dl=0

Comment: Why the `)` in `LEN)(`

Comment: `"LEN(" & Cells(lrNew, 11).Address & ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" & Cells(lrNew, 11).Address & ",""B"",""""))"`